# Content-type json returns http 404

Tags: web-applications, extjs, struts2, tomcat7

In a 3rd party server when web application (serverside Struts 2)  with EXt-JS 4 makes a ajax request with **content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8**  webserver returns page not found http 404/403 status code. But if we make the same request with plain text/html via browser url bar then response received. What will be the problem.

is there any way to simulate the request by sending in different content-type, i have tried below html form but it sends only **Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded**

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="http://abc.com/abc?" method="post" enctype="application/json; charset=utf-8">

<input type='submit'/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Can a server or tomcat can restrict particular content-type alone?

```
<action name="abc" class="com.stutzen.rhs.abc.Abc" method="abc">
        <interceptor-ref name="json">
            <!--param name="contentType">application/json</param-->
        </interceptor-ref>
        <result type="json">
            <param name="excludeProperties">
                data,model
            </param>
        </result>
    </action>
```

Comment: Sure, the server can analyze the request headers and return a response depending on what it finds.

Answer (score 1):

You can set arbitrary headers on Ext side when making request with Ext.Ajax.request:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url: '/foo',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    }
});
```

However it looks more like a hack than true solution; you need to find out what server expects and proceed accordingly.

Comment: thats good sample, i tried that and got response. But in serverside struts with json plugin it needs content-type as application/json. But anyway i got a blank result page. So class was loaded and it is serving the request for content-type other then application/json then why not for it alone. provided the struts configuration too in the question.

Comment: I can't help you with Struts configuration as I'm not familiar with it.